# Yocto Build error; Initialising tasks...ERROR: An uncaught exception occurred in runqueue (from Yocto newbies)

Tags: yocto

**The error:**

```
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6893303Z **Initialising tasks...ERROR: An uncaught exception occurred in runqueue**
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6894429Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6896192Z   File "/__w/1/s/msocs-rackmanager-bsp/yocto/bitbake/lib/bb/runqueue.py", line 1524, in RunQueue.execute_runqueue():
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6896660Z              try:
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6896927Z     >            return self._execute_runqueue()
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6897250Z              except bb.runqueue.TaskFailure:
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6898244Z   File "/__w/1/s/msocs-rackmanager-bsp/yocto/bitbake/lib/bb/runqueue.py", line 1474, in RunQueue._execute_runqueue():
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6899084Z                  self.rqdata.init_progress_reporter.next_stage()
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6899368Z     >            self.start_worker()
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6899675Z                  self.rqdata.init_progress_reporter.next_stage()
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6900270Z   File "/__w/1/s/msocs-rackmanager-bsp/yocto/bitbake/lib/bb/runqueue.py", line 1295, in RunQueue.start_worker():
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6900860Z              for mc in self.rqdata.dataCaches:
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6901154Z     >            self.worker[mc] = self._start_worker(mc)
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6901387Z      
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6902344Z   File "/__w/1/s/msocs-rackmanager-bsp/yocto/bitbake/lib/bb/runqueue.py", line 1268, in RunQueue._start_worker(mc='', fakeroot=False, rqexec=None):
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6902932Z              worker.stdin.write(b"<extraconfigdata>" + pickle.dumps(self.cooker.extraconfigdata) + b"</extraconfigdata>")
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6903397Z     >        worker.stdin.write(b"<workerdata>" + pickle.dumps(workerdata) + b"</workerdata>")
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6904226Z              worker.stdin.flush()
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6904497Z BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6904644Z 
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6905449Z ERROR: Running idle function
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6906161Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6908003Z   File "/__w/1/s/msocs-rackmanager-bsp/yocto/bitbake/lib/bb/cooker.py", line 1438, in buildTargetsIdle(server=<ProcessServer(ProcessServer-1, started)>, rq=<bb.runqueue.RunQueue object at 0x7fd16f08e4a8>, abort=False):
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6908771Z                  try:
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6910081Z     >                retval = rq.execute_runqueue()
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6910509Z                  except runqueue.TaskFailure as exc:
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6911385Z   File "/__w/1/s/msocs-rackmanager-bsp/yocto/bitbake/lib/bb/runqueue.py", line 1524, in RunQueue.execute_runqueue():
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6911836Z              try:
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6912141Z     >            return self._execute_runqueue()
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6912497Z              except bb.runqueue.TaskFailure:
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6913487Z   File "/__w/1/s/msocs-rackmanager-bsp/yocto/bitbake/lib/bb/runqueue.py", line 1474, in RunQueue._execute_runqueue():
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6913882Z                  self.rqdata.init_progress_reporter.next_stage()
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6914155Z     >            self.start_worker()
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6914634Z                  self.rqdata.init_progress_reporter.next_stage()
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6915413Z   File "/__w/1/s/msocs-rackmanager-bsp/yocto/bitbake/lib/bb/runqueue.py", line 1295, in RunQueue.start_worker():
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6915991Z              for mc in self.rqdata.dataCaches:
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6916309Z     >            self.worker[mc] = self._start_worker(mc)
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6916551Z      
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6917175Z   File "/__w/1/s/msocs-rackmanager-bsp/yocto/bitbake/lib/bb/runqueue.py", line 1268, in RunQueue._start_worker(mc='', fakeroot=False, rqexec=None):
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6917793Z              worker.stdin.write(b"<extraconfigdata>" + pickle.dumps(self.cooker.extraconfigdata) + b"</extraconfigdata>")
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6918746Z     >        worker.stdin.write(b"<workerdata>" + pickle.dumps(workerdata) + b"</workerdata>")
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6919101Z              worker.stdin.flush()
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6919963Z BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
2022-06-23T00:57:52.6920269Z 
2022-06-23T00:57:52.8226862Z 
2022-06-23T00:57:52.8228092Z Summary: There were 11 WARNING messages shown.
2022-06-23T00:57:52.8229138Z Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

**The bsp file has these lines:**

```
<remote fetch="https://git.yoctoproject.org/git" name="yocto"/>  
<remote fetch="git://git.openembedded.org" name="oe"/>
<remote> fetch="https://git.yoctoproject.org" name="ti"/>
```

I created a Linux VM using Hyper-V on a Windows system. I ran through the steps manually and created the build without issues. When I add the *similar* steps onto the Azure Pipeline, I ran into problem. I got this unhandled exception.

I don't have the Yocto code to look as I don't have access to the Azure build machine. I am not sure how to debug this issue and why I am seeing this failure. Can someone provide some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the issue. In my local VM build, there was no locale issue. When I use the Azure Dev Ops Pipeline, I ran into this error:

Please use a locale setting which supports UTF-8 (such as `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`).
Python can't change the filesystem locale after loading so we need a UTF-8 when Python starts or things won't work

I tried to fix this error. `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` didn't work. I fixed it using something. This error went away but later during Initialising tasks, I got the unhandled exception.

So I searched on the web and came up with this fix for the locale:

```bash
sudo apt-get install locales
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
# sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
cat "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8" > /etc/environment
cat "LANG=en_US.UTF-8" >> /etc/environment
cat /etc/environment > /etc/default/locale
```

I probably don't need all of them but I wanted to be sure. This got me passed the unhandled exception shown.

Comment: Why is there a commented line in the code snippet?